# Regular expression which checks number of digits

Tags: regex

I have a string which contains something like this `number: -7-972/516/57.15`
. Expression must return the number of digits and filter by first number. In result i want to see: `79725165715`
. I wrote this expression `^(\D*)+7+(\D*(?:\d\D*){10})$`, but that expression got problem "Catastrophic Backtracking"(freezes on execution) with long strings like: `bt.rfznascvd@rcs.ru,e.zovtrnko@lkn.ru`

Comment: Have you tested it on [regex tester](https://regex101.com/) ?

Comment: https://regexr.com/4ach8
this regex tester have same error as my kotlin program

Comment: Why do you have `+` after `(\D*)`? Since `\D*` already specifies that the characters can repeat, there's no point in using another quantifier after it. You're just repeating a repetition.

Comment: I.e. there's no difference between `(\D*)+7` and `(\D*)7`. If you want to require at least one non-numeric character before `7`, it should be `(\D+)7`.

Comment: A regexp can't return a count, it just returns the part of the input that matches it, along with the parts that match capturing groups. I also don't understand what you mean by "filter by first number".

Comment: A regexp can only match one contiguous string in the input. To get your return value, you have to use a regexp replacement function, and replace all the non-digit characters with an empty string.

Comment: Why not remove all non-digits? https://rextester.com/QZZ99067

Comment: I can use only regex match function, thats why i need this expression

Answer (score 0):

I write a new one and that works: `\D*7(\d\D*){10}`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use `\d`. Using of `Matches` will give you all matches in pattern from considered line. `Count` of it wwill give you count of matches. And for concatanate them to string I created small extension method.
For testing your regexes I can advice [regexlib](http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx).

```
namespace CSharpTest
{
    using System.Text;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = @"number: -7-972/516/57.15";

            var regex = new Regex(@"\d");

            var matches = regex.Matches(input);

            var countOfNumbers = matches.Count;
            var number = matches.ToNumber();
        }

        public static string ToNumber(this MatchCollection matches)
        {
            var result = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (Match match in matches)
                result.Append(match.Value);

            return result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its true, but i can only use one regex match to take a boolean result, without other functions

Comment: "Expression must return the number of digits", about what bool result you say?
And RegEx uses only for checking and gets matches from input. You can take bool value only as info about matches(https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=netframework-4.7.2)